# How to remove ??? characters on database query result with Laravel

Tags: vuejs2, laravel-5.5

I am have an issue that sounds new and don't know what is happening. I am retrieving data from database with Laravel eloquent.

In my controller:

```
public function index()
    {
        $suppliers = Supplier::all();
        return response()->json($suppliers);
    }
```

Its working just fine, the problem is the result object however is appearing as shown below with leading ???. All query results in the entire project is rendering just this way. I have tried to trim the project witn trim() but I realize this wont work on object.

> ����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������[{"id":1,"first_name":"Ronald","last_name":"Wekesa","mobile_number":"0717245218","work_phone":"07140000","phone_code":254,"fax":null,"email":"email@yaho.com","postal_address":"P.o
>   Box
>   323","town":"Kitale","zip":30200,"phisical_address":"Kiminini","company":"Wafutech","created_at":"2018-03-05
>   11:52:30","updated_at":"2018-03-05
>   11:52:30"},{"id":2,"first_name":"Ronald","last_name":"Wekesa","mobile_number":"0725645544","work_phone":"070025400","phone_code":2....

when I render the result in my vuejs front end as shown below I am getting blank loop, I mean the loop runs but with empty bullet list. I am suspecting this might have something with this fun behavior.
   **//My View component**

```
     <template>
    <div>
        <h3>Suppliers</h3>
               <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-10"></div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <router-link :to="{ name: 'create-supplier'}" class="btn btn-primary">Add Supplier</router-link>
          </div>
        </div><br />

        <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-responsive">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>First Name</td>
                <td>Last Name</td>
                <td>Company</td>
                <td>Mobile Phone</td>


            </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr v-for="supplier in suppliers">
                    <td>{{ supplier.first_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ supplier.last_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ supplier.company }}</td>
                    <td>{{ supplier.mobile_number }}</td>

                    <td><router-link :to="{name: 'edit-supplier', params: { id: supplier.id }}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</router-link></td>
                    <td><button class="btn btn-danger" v-on:click="deleteSupplier(supplier.id)">Delete</button></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>


<script>

    export default {
        name:'displayAsset',
        data(){
            return{
                suppliers: []

            }
        },

        created: function()
        {
            this.fetchSuppliers();
        },

        methods: {
            fetchSuppliers()
            {
              let uri = 'http://localhost/ims/public/api/suppliers';
              this.axios.get(uri).then((response) => {
                  this.suppliers = response.data;
              });
            },
            deleteSupplier(id)
            {
              let uri = `http://localhost/ims/public/api/suppliers/${id}`;
              this.suppliers.splice(id, 1);
              this.axios.delete(uri);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I have tried to re-install laravel but no difference. I have also re-installed my xampp server with the latest version but wan't lucky either. What is causing this and how can I resolve it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show more code. How do you populate suppplier?

Comment: What exactly you mean? The model or the way data is passed to supplier model?

Comment: I have to say I have never seen anything like that.  Can you look at your database and tell us what your default charset is set to? Also are you using phpmyadmin with xampp?

Comment: Yes I am using phpmyadmin xampp. I have never experienced similar issue and I am just abashed. I will check the db and come back to you.

Comment: I mean how are you, in the JavaScript code, setting the value of the  `suppliers` property that you are using in the `v-for`.

Comment: OK, I update the question

Comment: @ acdcjunior  I have updated the post with full JavaScript code. the v-for directive prints blank results whenever data is coming from the database though server results is shown in the console just fine but with leading white spance which shows as ??? in the browser.